# UISegmentedControl in Static UITableView IBOutlet Not Getting Set

Tags: xcode, uitableview, static, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UITableView which has static cells, inside one of those cells is a UISegmentedControl.  I've hooked up and IBOutlet to the control itself to the containing table view controller class.  However, when I break in ViewDidLoad, the outlet isn't even set, it's nil.  All other IBOutlets in that class are being set except for the UISegmentedControl.

Is this a bug?  Has anyone else experienced this?

Thanks

Comment: when you go to the storyboard and do a right click on the UISegmentedControl, can you see a link in the referencing outlet section?

Comment: Yes, absolutely it is set and is sticking in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Omg, this was all to do with localization.  It seems after turning on localization none of my storyboard changes were being honored.  I had to remove base localization and then re-add the storyboard to the project to fix this.

I hope this helps somebody else who may end up in the same situation.